# Rspec method returning a value which should be a redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have:

```
def redirect_if_no_user
  if current_user.nil?
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

in `ApplicatonController`. I would like to write a corresponding test:

```
Rspec.describe ApplicationController do

controller do
  def index
    render nothing: true
  end
end

describe '#redirect_if_no_user' do
  it 'redirects to root path' do
    get :index
    current_user = nil
    expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
  end
end

end
```

but I'm getting: `Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>`

Any help?

Comment: I can't see anywhere that you're calling an action in your test. Please share more code so that it is reproducable

Comment: There's still no get/post here. Where are you actually calling `index`

Comment: @Yule sorry yes. here you go

Comment: Is `redirect_if_no_user` set as a `before_action`?

Comment: @supersize then how does it get called?

Comment: @Vasfed it is called in another controller

Answer (score 1):

When you write `current_user = nil` it will set a local variable. You need to nil out the controller's `current_user` which comes from its `@current_user` instance var. Or stub out the controller's `current_user` method to return nil.

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous controller does not call the filter, so add:

```
controller do
  before_filter :redirect_if_no_user # so it is called
  def index
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

also test `expect(current_user).to be_nil if defined? current_user` just to ensure correct input

Comment: thanks, with using your expect, it works fine now. But how can I ensure that the redirect was successful?

Comment: @supersize keep your `expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)`, that other expectation is useful because `current_user` is usually not set in tests unless you want it to, but sometimes you can accidentally change this, just for ease of possible debug

Comment: but then I'm getting the error mentioned above. `...but was 200`

Comment: @supersize do you have auth stubs set up globally? Try additionally to stub it out before calling `get`: `expect(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(nil)`